# How to generate the legal forms in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to build a Legal Forms on my website. How can I build form like I attached in the image [check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBU4B.png)

Comment: You could use Contact Form 7 for this, you'll just have to add a bit CSS to change the styling of the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) apply this css to it's input fields

```css
input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name">
```